# classList showing undefined when accessed through array, stumped

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out what's going on:

Using this utility function to check IE8 event fallback:

```
function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
    return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
    return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}
```

I'm using a simple vanilla document.ready style checker. I've made sure this wasn't causing the problem.

```
domReady(function(event) {

  var menuButton = document.getElementById('nav-button');
  var menuButtonNav = document.getElementById('nav-main');
  var menuPageWrap = document.getElementById('nav-page-wrap'); 

  var menuEls = [ 
    menuPageWrap
  ];

  addEvent(menuButton, 'click', function(){
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i <= menuEls.length; i ++ ) {
      menuEls[i].classList.toggle('is--open')
    }
  }) 

  /*
  addEvent(menuButton, 'click', function(){
      menuButtonNav.classList.toggle('is--open');
      menuPageWrap.classList.toggle('is--open');
      menuButton.classList.toggle('is--open');
  });
  */

  console.log(menuEls[0])
  console.log(menuEls[0].classList)

});
```

So, when using the loop, I get the error 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined'.  I don't get the error using the commented code.  The console log returns the element fine and the classList fine.  It only happens with the wrapper element, for some reason, but the element is in the HTML plus it returns fine on the log.

The elements with their IDs are all in the DOM correctly.  I'm racking my brain trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Won't matter with IE8, see my answer.

Comment: Instead of "racking your brain", why don't you try debugging. Just step through your code line by line, and when landing on the offending statement, examine relevant values such as `menuEls[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for ( i = 0; i <= menuEls.length; i ++ )` exceeds the upper boundary of the array. It has to be `for ( i = 0; i < menuEls.length; i ++ )`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, I get it, thank you so much.  I'm still learning js and knew this one was staring me in the face.

Comment: For typos, better to VTC and/or comment.